# How to get count of Rows automatically when a New Row is added and Rows are to shown as Columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I am using this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbcount
PIVOT 
    (COUNT(Id) FOR Name IN (F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6)) p
```

and result is

```
F1 F2 F3 F4 F6 
9  9  8  8  8
```

But I have kept F1 TO F6 fixed I want that if a new column is added I will get count automatically without keeping it fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below - using dynamic pivot

```
declare @sql varchar(max)='',@col_list varchar(8000)=''

set @col_list = (select distinct quotename([Name])+',' from tbcount
for xml path(''))

set @col_list = left (@col_list,len(@col_list)-1)

set @sql = 'select '+@col_list+' from
tbcount
pivot (count(id) for [Name] in ('+@col_list+'))pv'

exec(@sql)
```

Comment: previous query was also correct and also what is the meaning of xml path in that

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(max) = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Quotename(Name) 
         FROM tbcount
         FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''); 

DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(max) = ' SELECT *
                                    FROM  tbcount
                                           PIVOT ( COUNT(Id) 
                                                 FOR Name IN ('+@cols+') ) pvt';
EXECUTE(@query)
```

This is the answer